# Android Gingerbread source code compiling error

Tags: android, compilation, rule

I need to compile the Android Gingerbread source code. I am using Ubuntu 10.04, 64 bit OS, but I get this error:

> make: *** No rule to make target `out/debug/host/linux-x86/pr/sim/obj/lib/libdl.so', needed by `out/debug/host/linux-x86/pr/sim/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libnfc_intermediates/LINKED/libnfc.so'.  Stop.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is 64-bit or 32-bit? If you are running a 64-bit machine, you may have to install the 32-bit compatibility libraries. [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/454253/how-to-run-32-bit-app-in-ubuntu-64-bit) may be more helpful: